# Blazor Syncfusion SfDashboardLayout - How can i update without refreshing the page

Tags: asynchronous, blazor, syncfusion, syncfusion-blazor

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse align-items-center">
    <div class="mb-1">
        <Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.SfButton IconCss="e-icons e-page-column-one" @onclick="@(async () => { await UpdatePanelData(1); await dashboardLayout.RefreshAsync(); })" class="me-1"></Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.SfButton>
        <Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.SfButton IconCss="e-icons e-page-column-two" @onclick="@(() => UpdatePanelData(2) )" class="me-1"></Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.SfButton>
        <Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.SfButton IconCss="e-icons e-page-column-right" @onclick="@(() => UpdatePanelData(3))" class="me-1"></Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.SfButton>
        <Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.SfButton IconCss="e-icons e-page-column-left" @onclick="@(() => UpdatePanelData(4))"></Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.SfButton>
    </div>
</div>
```

it's my button, i want's update this layout;

```
<Syncfusion.Blazor.Layouts.SfDashboardLayout CellSpacing="new double[] { 10, 10 }" AllowDragging AllowFloating AllowResizing @ref=dashboardLayout Columns="8" CellAspectRatio="@aspectRatio">
    <Syncfusion.Blazor.Layouts.DashboardLayoutEvents Changed="PanelsChanged"></Syncfusion.Blazor.Layouts.DashboardLayoutEvents>
```

and it's my method:

```
async Task UpdatePanelData(int selectedId)
{
    using (var con = await ContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
    {
        var panels = await dashboardLayout.Serialize();
        switch (selectedId)
        {
            case 1:
                int column1 = 2;
                foreach (var panel in panels)
                {
                    //assignment
                }
                await con.SaveChangesAsync();

                break;
            case 2:
                int row2 = 0, count2 = 1;

                foreach (var panel in panels)
                {
                    //assignment
                }
                await con.SaveChangesAsync();

                break;
            case 3:
                int row3 = 0, count3 = 1;

                foreach (var panel in panels)
                {
                   //assignment
                }
                await con.SaveChangesAsync();

                break;
            case 4:
                int row4 = 0, count4 = 1;

                foreach (var panel in panels)
                {
                   //assignment
                }
                await con.SaveChangesAsync();
                break;
        }
        StateHasChanged();
        await dashboardLayout.RefreshAsync();
    }
}
```

I created the buttons to give a ready-made theme to the panels coming to the layout. The method works and the data in the db is updated, but I need to refresh the page to see this. How can I make the button change in appearance when I press it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the shared details, we suspect that you are adding panels to the **Dashboard Layout** component. We suggest you check the serialized panel once; after that, there is no need to use the "**RefreshAsync**" method. We have already achieved a similar scenario regarding changing the panels dynamically with predefined values.

**Sample Browser** : https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/dashboard-layout/default?theme=fluent

Additionally, if you want to change the button appearance when you click on it, we suggest utilizing the "**IsToggle**" property, which helps change the button appearance when you click on it.

**Sample Browser** : https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/buttons/default-functionalities?theme=fluent

**Sample Browser** : https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/blazor/Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.SfButton.html#Syncfusion_Blazor_Buttons_SfButton_IsToggle